# How does i-nigma app supports all mobile platforms?

Tags: android, iphone, qr-code, barcode-scanner

Does anyone here knows why and how the i-nigma app can be integrated into all mobile platforms? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it has been ported to all the platforms that it has been ported to. What are you really asking?